# Logstash throws [message=>"undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass"] when Elasticsearch index template defined in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, elk

I am trying to load data from sql server to elastic search using logstash. For index creation i am using index template that is specified in the config file of logstash.

**Output field of logstash.config :**

```
 output{ 
    stdout { codec => json_lines } 
    elasticsearch { 
                    hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
                                             document_id => "%{[id]}" 
                                             manage_template => true                     
                                             template => "C:/Users/Lich/Documents/logstash-7.10.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.10.1/logstash_test.json" 
                                             template_name => "logstash_test" 
                                             template_overwrite => true 
            } 
    }
```

**Error while running logstash :**

```
    [2021-01-25T19:48:28,232][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]} 
[2021-01-25T19:48:28,298][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using mapping template from {:path=>"C:/Users/Lich/Documents/logstash-7.10.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.10.1/logstash_test.json"} 
[2021-01-25T19:48:28,370][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000, "pipeline.sources"=>["C:/Users/Lich/Documents/logstash-7.10.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.10.1/sampleconf.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x797ce1a8 run>"} 
[2021-01-25T19:48:28,509][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Failed to install template. {:message=>"undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass", :class=>"NoMethodError", :backtrace=>["C:/Users/Lich/Documents/logstash-7.10.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.10.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:42:in `add_ilm_settings_to_template'", "C:/Users/Lich/Documents/logstash-7.10.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.10.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:15:in `install_template'", "C:/Users/Lich/Documents/logstash-7.10.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.10.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:218:in `install_template'", "C:/Users/Lich/Documents/logstash-7.10.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.10.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:49:in `block in setup_after_successful_connection'"]} 
[2021-01-25T19:48:28,546][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Creating rollover alias <logstash-{now/d}-000001> 
[2021-01-25T19:48:29,463][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>1.08} 
[2021-01-25T19:48:29,802][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"} 
[2021-01-25T19:48:29,888][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
```

**Index template configuration:**

```
{ 
   "index_patterns":"*-logstash_test-*", 
   "priority":1, 
   "template":{ 
      "settings":{ 
            "analysis":{ 
               "analyzer":{ 
                  "test_autocomplete":{ 
                     "tokenizer":"test_tokenizer" 
                  } 
               }, 
               "tokenizer":{ 
                  "test_tokenizer":{ 
                     "custom_token_chars":"'-", 
                     "max_gram":"3", 
                     "min_gram":"3", 
                     "token_chars":[ 
                         
                     ], 
                     "type":"ngram" 
                  } 
               } 
            }, 
         "mappings":{ 
            "properties":{ 
               "test_id":{ 
                  "type":"text", 
                  "analyzer":"test_autocomplete" 
               } 
            } 
         } 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Although it fails the index gets created with the data, but the analyzers specified in the `settings{..}` does not reflect. I am new to ELK stack and not sure on why this is happening.

> **Elasticsearch Version : 7.10.1**

> **Logstash Version : 7.10.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your `logstash_test.json` file has the following format:

```
{
  "index_patterns": "*-logstash_test-*",
  "order": 1,
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "test_autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "test_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "test_tokenizer": {
          "custom_token_chars": "'-",
          "max_gram": "3",
          "min_gram": "3",
          "token_chars": [],
          "type": "ngram"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "test_id": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "test_autocomplete"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You had `mappings` and `settings` enclosed within the `template` section, but this is only for the new [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html) which the `elasticsearch` Logstash output doesn't support yet. You need to use the [legacy index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates-v1.html).

Comment: Hi, thanku so much it worked. but i can see that the index is not getting created with the new **index_patterns** name i mentioned in the index template. Instead it is getting created as below:
`[logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "order"=>1, "settings"=>{"number_of_shards"=>2, "analysis"=>{"analyzer"=> ...`

Comment: You need to specify the desired index name that matches your index pattern in the `elasticsearch` output otherwise Logstash will name it `logstash-xyz` by default

Comment: Silly me, Thank you! you're a life saver!!